# SimpleFramework: OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Tags: out-of-memory, bytebuffer, simple-framework

I'm using simpleframework to implement an HTTP server that, among other things, handles large images (4m to 8m).

I noticed that after a while the application throws a OutOfMemory exception and stops handling further requests.
Using jconsole, I see that the direct memory is increased, but it's never deallocated. The exception that is thrown is this:

```
2014/08/27 17:30:28 | Exception in thread "Dispatcher: Thread-17" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
2014/08/27 17:30:28 |   at org.simpleframework.transport.BufferWrapper.write(BufferWrapper.java:356)
```

I tried to increase the direct memory size (-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize) to 800m, but it only delayed the OutOfMemory exception.

Has anyone had this problem? Is there anything that can be done to deallocate this memory?

I'm using the latest version of simpleframework (5.1.6) on a Windows Server 2003 x64 box.

Best regards,

Telmo Simões

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with version 6.0. It is not officially released however the API is unlikely to change much when it is finally released. Also there has been a redesign of the memory allocation on the output buffers. It also supports WebSockets out of the box.

https://github.com/ngallagher/simpleframework

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried the latest version, but the problem is still there (exception throw when executing SocketBuffer.flush(...)). Is there anything else that might help to resolve this error?

Comment: Has Simple moved to github?

Answer (score -1):

OOM exception can have many reasons. A detailed analysis will be required of the cause. heap dumps will help. Add VM params for heap dump on OOM exception. Also try to increase your heap size and try again.